# apache camel - deploying with cxfs web service

Tags: deployment, localhost, apache-camel

I'm trying to deploy my camel app which on start is creating a cxfrs endpoint.  The url is like this: `http://localhost:9876` .  When I try to hit this one on a rest client or anywhere within my machine it works.  But when I try to access it using my phone or other external devices, I'm not able to connect.

Am I missing something?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `localhost` will mean it is only accessible to your local machine, using `0.0.0.0` instead should make it publicly accessible.

Answer (score 1):

0.0.0.0 should bind all available network interface on your remote machine, but from your description, somehow it only bind to localhost|127.0.0.1 so only accessible from local machine, could you use
http://external.ip.address:9876/foo/FooService

instead to see if it helps?

Also, you can try to access other network service(for example start a tomcat on remote machine and see if you can access it from your local machine) from that remote machine to see if it works, this can determine if your DNS correct or if there's really no firewall between them.